# How does Manhattan and Euclidean distance combine to control grease pencil input?

Tags: grease-pencil

[image]

I read the wiki (https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:DE/2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Sketching/Drawing)
and I can understand the difference among the definitions, as I understand it says the same with different words, also the hints.
[image]

[image]

if I set Euclidean value to 100px I can predict that Manhattan distance will control the minimum distance to draw the new gp point, but if I set a 0 or 1 or 10 on the Euclidean changing the Manhattan distance doesn't do any evident change.

So I'm trying to understand this and I'm feeling a bit lost here.

Answer (score 1):

On this picture from Wikipedia green is Euclidean distance , rest - Manhattan distances. If the square was 10 by 10, then  Mathattan distance is 20, Euclidean sqrt(200), so around 14. So Euclidean distance  will be the real distance the mouse traveled, Manhattan - the number of pixels it travelled. Although it seems Blender uses the number of pixels per axis (probably taking maximum rather than summing them). In this case Manhattan distance will be 10.

[image]

Comment: Im feeling like an idiot i can't predict the parameter result even by try and error, but as i see if the minimum distance in blender its 0 pixels or 1 pixel (square) ¿shouldn't euclidean be enough?

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure what the question is. So it will connect current mouse position to the point that was drawn previously only when you moved your mouse a certain distance away  - either n pixels  in Manhattan distance or d in  Euclidean distance, and this parameters you can change.

Comment: for example, if I would like to generate points every 10px fixed, and not be modified by speed ¿how should I set up it?
In the other hand if i want the points to be created every 10px but in this case I want that the speed affect the creation of the points.
Will the points created based on the speed of the stroke will be created over or below the 10px limit?

Comment: @Nahuel Belich in my setup the drawing is always unaffected but the speed, only by the distance. Is setting both distances to 10px not doing what you want?

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=105855).
as you see in the image the point placement change depending on the speed, now im thinking that could be do to interpolation and refresh rate rather than a grease pencil property. 
Well i now grab a ruler and i started to get some of it, but need to confirm a few things.
Manhattan literally is the threshold for horizontal and vertical movement if the cursor its move in straight line (wacom+plastic ruler).
If the cursor does not move in a perfect line then Euclidean distance starts to work in the case radius from last point

Comment: Mmm, can't really tell, maybe there are some other settings. E.g. if you use a tablet it also takes pressure into account.